# PHP5 to PHP7 upgrade issue: array as object key parameter

Tags: php, arrays, object

The problem is that when using PHP7 the expected result is different from PHP5, see following example with $object2.

I think that the three methods are equivalent from each other, but it seems not to be true.

It seems that in PHP7 the shortcut used with $object2 return the type of variable instead of the value.

Is there some environment configuration of PHP7 that makes it behave like PHP5 with respect to this issue?

```
$array1 = array();
$array1["Key"] = "Value"; 
$object1 = new stdClass();
$key1 = $array1["Key"];
$object1->Stream = new stdClass();
$object1->Stream->$key1 = 5;
echo json_encode($object1);

$array2 = array();
$array2["Key"] = "Value"; 
$object2 = new stdClass();
$object2->Stream = new stdClass();
$object2->Stream->$array2["Key"] = 5;
echo json_encode($object2);

$array3 = array();
$array3 = "Value"; 
$object3 = new stdClass();
$object3->Stream = new stdClass();
$object3->Stream->$array3 = 5;
echo json_encode($object3);
```

Result in PHP5:

```
{"Stream":{"Value":5}}

{"Stream":{"Value":5}}

{"Stream":{"Value":5}}
```

Result in PHP7:

```
{"Stream":{"Value":5}}

{"Stream":{"Array":{"Key":5}}}

{"Stream":{"Value":5}}
```

Comment: BTW: For developing, turn on notices, then you would see, that PHP emmits a notice: `Notice: Array to string conversion in ... on line ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it in {}

```
$object2->Stream->{$array2["Key"]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Anyway I'm trying not to change my actual code of $object2 implementation because this is an abstract concept that I have used extensively on a big project.

Comment: When you do not want to change code, then don't ask questions, how to modify you code, to get the desired result...

Comment: My final question was "Is there some environment configuration of PHP7 that makes it behave like PHP5 with respect to this issue?". thanks for your support.

Comment: I don't know of any setting that will change the behaviour for php7. I am surprised php5 treats it differently to php7.  Perhaps ask on the php website

Answer (score 0):

You can Store array index in varaible then use this variable in object

Try follwoing code

```
$array1 = array();
$array1["Key"] = "Value"; 
$object1 = new stdClass();
$key1 = $array1["Key"];
$object1->Stream = new stdClass();
$object1->Stream->$key1 = 5;
echo json_encode($object1);

$array2 = array();
$array2["Key"] = "Value"; 
$tmp = $array2["Key"];
$object2 = new stdClass();
$object2->Stream = new stdClass();
$object2->Stream->$tmp = 5;
echo json_encode($object2);

$array3 = array();
$array3 = "Value"; 
$object3 = new stdClass();
$object3->Stream = new stdClass();
$object3->Stream->$array3 = 5;
echo json_encode($object3);
```

Comment: Your solution is the same that I have used in $object1 example. I'm searching a solution without changing the actual code of my $object2 implementation.